# Reflection: ClassSymbol to string representation

Tags: scala, reflection

Given a [`ClassSymbol`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Symbols%24ClassSymbol) at runtime, what's the best way to get a string representation of the symbol's declaration?

For example: I have a symbol for `class Foo` which, in the original source, was declared as

```
class Foo extends Bar with UselessMixin
```

How can I get a string representation similar to

```
"Foo extends Bar with UselessMixin"
```

Type parameters would be useful as well.

Comment: You can't. A symbol doesn't have any information about how it is represented in a source file nor how it is created or to which types it belongs. What you need is a tree.

Comment: I've been able to get print out "Foo with Bar with UselessMixin <followed by all members of the symbol>" with classSymbol.typeSignature.toString. I just want the first part, without the members.